# How can I best design a retail store bill  to communicate special offers?

Tags: e-commerce, billing

I am designing an application for a retail store, and have a situation where I need to find a solution for a billing summary on the device. The client needs a lot of data on the screen but apart from that we have three cases which need to be communicated through text.

1. Buy 100 of Product A and Get 10 Free
2. Buy 100 of Product B and Pay For 90
3. Buy 100 of Product C and Get 10 of Product D Free

I have searched on the internet for specimen copy which can give a good answer to this, and for methods of representing all these cases in same screen and data table, but am unable to find an answer.

Can you make any suggestions for my specific case, or alternatively can you please help me find any research or any guidelines for good bill design for the retail market that would allow me to come up with a solution?

Comment: Hi @ajayashish, I tidied up your question a bit and tried to focus on what you we asking. Feel free to revert or let me know if I didn't quite get it right.

Comment: Are you asking about how to advertise the offer on bills in general (e.g., how to promote this), or how to reflect the free/discounted product on a specific bill after the customer takes advantage of the promotion (e.g., what the bill line items should say)?

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, your text looks good already. I'm not sure there's a better way to communicate it than what you have. Are you trying to convey this information in another way?

Answer (score 1):

I think emphasizing the discount is what works, at least it seems to be the pattern. Most e-commerce sites show you the full price, then the discount.

Answer (score 0):

Suggest a table to show product, count and cost, with a total at the bottom. The formatting here is pretty rubbish but hope it is clear enough:

### Option 1

Item | Count | Cost

Product A | 100 | $100

Product A | 10 | $0
Total £100

### Option 2

Item | Count | Cost

Product B | 100 | $100

Discount | 10% | -$10

Total £90

### Option 3

Item | Count | Cost

Product C | 100 | $100

Product D | 10 | $0

Total £100

Comment: I actually don't understand this -- perhaps make a mockup instead using the data table? Also, the currency got mixed up in some places.